# Mono GTK# view list with multiple views (icons, details, list etc)

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I'm writing my first Mono GTK# app, and need a list control that can support multiple views, eg a list, details, icons (similar to Windows Explorer).

I basically need a widget that is a TreeView, IconView and NodeView all in one.

Preferably I would like to also group the nodes into sub nodes.

My application is a Metadata grabber for movies, where I could have 1000 movies.  I would like to group them by letter, so "A" would be a tree node and under than I would have "Armageddon", "Antz", "A Knights Tale" etc, and I would like to view those movies as icons (showing poster and the title), and details (showing title, star rating, file size, file location etc).

I achieved this using the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html) control in my original WinForms application, but decided this app would be better suited in Mono / GTK# so it can run on multiple platforms (i.e. Mac and Linux).

Is there any such widget, or can I customize the TreeView or IconView to achieve what I am after?

TIA

Comment: My first guess would be to add those three views to your app but hide two of them. You might take a look at the Nautilus source code (Gnome's file manager) which, like most file managers, is able to switch between these views.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I'm unable to comment on this question, so I just post an answer.

In Gtk# you can achieve both: TreeView and NodeView using the `Gtk.TreeView` widget, however it won't be as easy as in .NET.

The IconView will be a little bit harder to implement. You will have to use lots of little widgets like `Gtk.Frame`, `Gtk.Table`, `Gtk.HBox` and `Gtk.VBox` to achieve decent look.

In Gtk# nothing is easy unfortunately.

Answering your question: Yes, there is a `Gtk.TreeView` widget and lots of other small components to build your IconView from. They are very customisable, but as I said before it's not an easy task.

I hope this helps.